# php - cut string until specific character

Tags: php, string, substring

I looked at some earlier stackoverflow questions, but I couldn't find what I wanted anywhere:

I want to split a string obtained using `$_GET` until a specific character.

Here is a sample url: `mywebsite/savettimes.php?time=1%3A15%2E123`

The stuff after 'time=' is basically just a time, like 1:13.123. I want to get only the minutes, 1 in this case. I can just use `substr()`, but the problem is I don't know how many digits the minutes is going to be. It might be 1 or 2.

I tried using multiple if statements, but I want a better method.

```
$time = $_GET['time'];
if (strlen($time) == 6) {//If only 1 digit of minutes is there
  $min = substr($time, 0, 1);
} else if (strlen($time) == 7) {
  $min = substr($time, 0, 1);
}
```

So, I want to split the string until the ':'. How do I do this?

Comment: Explode by `%3A` or `:` after `urldecode`

Comment: Can somebody please tell me what was wrong with my question?

Comment: I din't downvote since I answered, but maybe lack of research effort and many similar or exact questions that could be found.

Comment: Ok, now I have added some attempts that I did earlier(before posting this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with `strstr` which can return everything before the first `:` occurrence:

```
$min = strstr($_GET['time'], ':', true);
```

Or to get seconds.micro-seconds as well:

```
list($min, $sec) = explode(':', $_GET['time']);
```

Comment: Take care that micro-seconds are separated from seconds with a dot. You can do `list($min, $sec, $mic) = sscanf($_GET['time'], '%d:%d.%s');` instead. However be carefull with the leading zeros in `$mic`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "23:13.123.";
$minute =  substr($url, 0, strpos($url, ':'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$time = $_GET['time'];
$timeParts = explode(":", $time);
$minute = $timeParts[0];
```

Note: using `$_GET['']` with no filter is not reccomended but it's not related to this question.